# How to share a Data Extension to different BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am able to see shared Data Extension folder in my account but i am not able to see any Share option visible in DE properties or anywhere like in Email Studio->Content . How can i share a Data Extension to different BU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy + Paste from documentation

Data Extension Permissions is a tool to control business units access to shared data extension. By checking the box next to a permission, you can enable or disable that permission.

> 1.Click **Subscribers**.
>
> 2.Click **Shared Data Extension**.
>
> 3.Select the data extension name.
>
> 4.Click **Permissions**.
>
> 5.Select the checkbox next to the names of the business unit to set or change permissions for. When
>   multiple business units are selected, existing permissions do not
>   display. To review a specific business unit's permissions, only select
>   the checkbox next that business unit.
>
> 6.Click **Edit**.
>
> 7.Set to allow or deny actions the business unit can take on the data extension.
>
> 8.Optionally,
>   set a **Start Sharing** and **End Sharing date.**
>
> 9.Click **Save**.

For Content,

> 1. Sharing components from existing Business Units:  a.    Ensure that the BU has access to the shared folder i.   While in the parent business
>      unit, Navigate to content builder
>
> ii.    Click on “Shared” in the left-hand panel.
>
> iii.  Right click the folder that with the shared content and select
>   “Modify Sharing. iv.  Select the BU that requires the sharing
>   permission.
>
> b.    To share components, add contents to the sharing folder: i. Select
>   the component you want to share the Content Builder Grid. ii. Expand
>   on the drop-down menu by the item iii.    Select Share Select business
>   units that can access the component.

**Resources**:

- http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/setting_ent_20_shared_data_extension_permissions/

Comment: Thanks for the Info it's really helpful. I have shared the DE with the a Particular BU. But not able to see the DE in the BU i shared with any thoughts. I replicated all the above steps.